# Rounding the total in BIP report

Tags: obiee

I see total like below in one of my BIP report.
Can I restrict the value to 2 digit after decimal.
In this example: 174264.87.  I tried to find the option

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with column properties and click data format tab

[image: sory for different language]

Comment: This is BI Publisher report based on direct data base objects based data model  and not BI Analysis/Answers and hence I guess we can not get column properties options as you depicted.